# Mailto link causes Chrome to crash

Tags: google-chrome

I am developing an application for an environment where `Chrome Version 29.0.1547.62` is used.

As part of the application, there is a requirement for a mailto: link. When this link is clicked, MS Outlook opens with the provided information in a new message.

In general this works as expected, however **the following string causes Chrome (including all other Chrome windows) to crash** with a message that begins with 'Whoa!'

```
> mailto:xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.xxx?body=xxxxxxx%0A%0Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> %0A%0Axxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxx%0A xxxx%0A xxxx%0A xxxx%0A xxxx%0A
> xxxx%0A%0A xxxxxxx xxx
```

I have obviously removed all personal information, but the structure is otherwise the same. The issue can be replicated by pasting the link into the `omnibox`.

Removing one of the x's from the end will cause it to work correctly, making it appear to be a length issue, however simply having a longer body made solely of x's doesn't cause an issue.

My question is:

**Has this issue been specifically resolved in a later version of Chrome?** If so, then a simple ($.browser.chrome && $.browser.version == 29) check would be sufficient, but if it has not, then I will have more of a problem.

Unfortunately the common fix for adding the GMail handler is not appropriate here, and it is also not possible to add any command line arguments to Chrome on start up, limiting the amount of debug information I can provide.

Comment: This sounds like a question that belongs in the Chrome bug tracker.

Comment: That sounds sensible: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=382907. I'd still like to hear if anyone here has any insight on the issue.